# To make the shuffled choices appear?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I print_r($choices) it shows that the array is shuffled but when I don't print nothing happens. Is there a possibility to apply/merge the shuffled choices with the radio button.

Here is the output:
[image: Output]

**View:**

```
 <?php if(count($questions) > 0):?>
        <?php $index = 1; ?>

        <?php foreach($questions as $row):?>

        <p><?=$index++?>. <b><?=$row->ques?></b></p>

        <?php $choices= array($row->ch_des1, $row->ch_des2, $row->ch_des3, $row->ch_des4);
       shuffle($choices);
       print_r($choices);
       ?>


        <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des1?>"> <?=$row->ch_des1?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des2?>"> <?=$row->ch_des2?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des3?>"> <?=$row->ch_des3?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$row->ch_des4?>"> <?=$row->ch_des4?><br> 

        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php else:?>
            <tr>
                <td>No records found!</td>
            </tr>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<?php if(count($questions) > 0):?>
        <?php $index = 1; ?>


<?php foreach($questions as $row):?>

    <p><?=$index++?>. <b><?=$row->ques?></b></p>

    <?php 
        $choices= array($row->ch_des1, $row->ch_des2, $row->ch_des3, $row->ch_des4);
        shuffle($choices);
    ?>
    <?php foreach($choices as $ch_des):?>
        <input type="radio" name="ch_id<?=$row->ch_id?>" value="<?=$ch_des?>"> <?=$ch_des?><br>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php else:?>
    <tr>
        <td>No records found!</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you.